# Combine two entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I Have an MVC project which uses EF Core . I've created virtual Dto's to select logical queries from my DB. Now I'm stuck , I have a method

```
    public IEnumerable<FinalEntity> getTest(int month,int year)
    {
        var dataFromSpecialPayments = _sabresRepository.GetBrokerMonthlyCommissionSpecialPayments(month, year);
        var dataFromTotals = _sabresRepository.GetBrokerMonthlyCommissionTotals(month, year);
```

These two variables contains the data after the logic and the aggregation , and have a relation between them of 1:1 by their `ID`(though there are plenty records without a match in the other table, so it's need to be a full join). Now I need to join this two entities into my final entity . These are the Dto's :

```
public class BrokerMonthlyCommission_Total_AggDto : DtoBase
{
    public int BrokerId { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalCommissionAmountBruto { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalCommissionAmountNeto { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalDistributingFeeParticipation { get; set; }
    public string BrokerName { get; set; }
    public int? CommissionPaymentStatusPl { get; set; }
    public int? MinCommissionForPayment { get; set; }
} 

public class BrokerMonthlyCommission_SpecialPayment_AggDto
{
    public int BrokerId { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalSpecialPayments { get; set; }
    public int PaymentStatus { get; set; }
}

public class FinalDto : DtoBase
{
    public int BrokerId { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalCommissionAmountBruto { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalCommissionAmountNeto { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalDistributingFeeParticipation { get; set; }
    public string BrokerName { get; set; }
    public int? CommissionPaymentStatusPl { get; set; }
    public int? MinCommissionForPayment { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalSpecialPayments { get; set; }
    public int PaymentStatus { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do this ? I know I can probably run with a foreach loop and iterate through every record, but I'm looking for a better solution

Comment: What have you tried? Loop over one collection, find the matching DTO in the other collection, and project onto `new FinalDto { X = x.X, Y = y.Y, ...}`? If you want to fix this using a database join, you've probably got to ditch the repository approach or extend either repository with a method to return the objects you want.

Comment: I thought about doing it in the database, but each table has to be aggregated before the join (this is what the methods do), so the linq query becomes very complicated for me

Comment: @Yossi, I edited my answer to use union of left join and right join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query use union of left join and right join. The commissionTotal has BrokerId of 1, 2 and 3. The commissionSpecial has BrokerId of 1, 2, and 4. Result is BrokerId of 1, 2, 3 and 4.

```
void Main()
{
    var commissionTotal = new []
    {
        new BrokerMonthlyCommission_Total_AggDto { BrokerId = 1, TotalCommissionAmountBruto = 1000, TotalCommissionAmountNeto = 1000,
            TotalDistributingFeeParticipation = 1000, BrokerName = "B1", CommissionPaymentStatusPl = 1, MinCommissionForPayment = 2 },
        new BrokerMonthlyCommission_Total_AggDto { BrokerId = 2, TotalCommissionAmountBruto = 2000, TotalCommissionAmountNeto = 2000,
            TotalDistributingFeeParticipation = 2000, BrokerName = "B2", CommissionPaymentStatusPl = 1, MinCommissionForPayment = 2 },
        new BrokerMonthlyCommission_Total_AggDto { BrokerId = 3, TotalCommissionAmountBruto = 3000, TotalCommissionAmountNeto = 3000,
            TotalDistributingFeeParticipation = 2000, BrokerName = "B3", CommissionPaymentStatusPl = 1, MinCommissionForPayment = 2 }
    };

    var commissionSpecial = new []
    {
        new BrokerMonthlyCommission_SpecialPayment_AggDto { BrokerId = 1, TotalSpecialPayments = 100, PaymentStatus = 1 },
        new BrokerMonthlyCommission_SpecialPayment_AggDto { BrokerId = 2, TotalSpecialPayments = 300, PaymentStatus = 2 },
        new BrokerMonthlyCommission_SpecialPayment_AggDto { BrokerId = 4, TotalSpecialPayments = 900, PaymentStatus = 4 }
    };

    var leftJoin =
        from ct in commissionTotal
        join cs in commissionSpecial on ct.BrokerId equals cs.BrokerId into temp
        from cs in temp.DefaultIfEmpty(new BrokerMonthlyCommission_SpecialPayment_AggDto
        {
            BrokerId = ct.BrokerId,
            TotalSpecialPayments = default(decimal),
            PaymentStatus = default(int)
        })
        select new {CT = ct, CS = cs};

    var rightJoin =
        from cs in commissionSpecial
        join ct in commissionTotal on cs.BrokerId equals ct.BrokerId into temp
        from ct in temp.DefaultIfEmpty(new BrokerMonthlyCommission_Total_AggDto
        {
            BrokerId = cs.BrokerId,
            TotalCommissionAmountBruto = default(decimal),
            TotalCommissionAmountNeto = default(decimal),
            TotalDistributingFeeParticipation = default(decimal),
            BrokerName = default(string),
            CommissionPaymentStatusPl = default(int?),
            MinCommissionForPayment = default(int?)
        })
        select new {CT = ct, CS = cs};

    var final = leftJoin.Union(rightJoin).Select(x => new FinalDto
    {
        BrokerId = x.CT.BrokerId,
        TotalCommissionAmountBruto = x.CT.TotalCommissionAmountBruto,
        TotalCommissionAmountNeto = x.CT.TotalCommissionAmountNeto,
        TotalDistributingFeeParticipation = x.CT.TotalDistributingFeeParticipation,
        BrokerName = x.CT.BrokerName,
        CommissionPaymentStatusPl = x.CT.CommissionPaymentStatusPl,
        MinCommissionForPayment = x.CT.MinCommissionForPayment,
        TotalSpecialPayments = x.CS.TotalSpecialPayments,
        PaymentStatus = x.CS.PaymentStatus
    });
    final.Dump(); // remove this line if not in LinqPad
}

public class BrokerMonthlyCommission_Total_AggDto
{
    public int BrokerId { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalCommissionAmountBruto { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalCommissionAmountNeto { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalDistributingFeeParticipation { get; set; }
    public string BrokerName { get; set; }
    public int? CommissionPaymentStatusPl { get; set; }
    public int? MinCommissionForPayment { get; set; }
}

public class BrokerMonthlyCommission_SpecialPayment_AggDto
{
    public int BrokerId { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalSpecialPayments { get; set; }
    public int PaymentStatus { get; set; }
}

public class FinalDto
{
    public int BrokerId { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalCommissionAmountBruto { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalCommissionAmountNeto { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalDistributingFeeParticipation { get; set; }
    public string BrokerName { get; set; }
    public int? CommissionPaymentStatusPl { get; set; }
    public int? MinCommissionForPayment { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalSpecialPayments { get; set; }
    public int PaymentStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Result in LinqPad:
[image]

Note:

1. I removed the inheritance from `DtoBase` because I didn't have that class.
2. `BrokerName` is null for `BrokerId` = 4 because it's a right join from `BrokerMonthlyCommission_SpecialPayment_AggDto` and it doesn't have a `BrokerName` property.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it and report back

Comment: @Yossi, I made a small improvement for more compact code. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: Yea I've fixed it my self :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this basically using select from System.Linq library and manually convert your types to FinalDto.

```
var dataFromSpecialPayments = _sabresRepository.GetBrokerMonthlyCommissionSpecialPayments(month, year)
    .Select(x => new FinalDto
    {
        BrokerId = x.BrokerId,
        //assign other properties
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Linq Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

```
dataFromSpecialPayments.Join(dataFromTotals,
  sp => sp.Id,
  ft => ft.Id,
  (specialPayment, fromTotal) => new FinalDto 
  {
    BrokerId = specialPayment.BrokerId,
    /// etc
  })
  .ToList()
```

Comment: Btw, what kind of join is it? inner? becuase I need a full outer join

Comment: Thanks, this almost works perfect, I just need an outer join instead on normal join.. How can I do that?